# Java API not querying as I would expect

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm using the newer 8.1 Java API for Elastic in Kotlin, and getting behavior that isn't what I would expect, nor what I get when using the manual REST API.  Here's my code:

```
val boolQuery = BoolQuery.of { boolBuilder -> boolBuilder
    .must { mustBuilder ->
        query.forEachIndexed { index, char ->
            val prefix = if (index > 0) {
                "* "
            } else { "" }

            val queryString = QueryStringQuery.of { queryBuilder -> queryBuilder
                .query("${prefix}${char}*")
            }

            mustBuilder.queryString(queryString)
        }
        mustBuilder
    }
}
```

In practice this only appears to hit on the last string query.  With an input of `query="rp"` I would expect the following request to be made:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                { "query_string" : { "query" : "r*" } },
                { "query_string" : { "query" : "* p*" } }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When running that exact request, it *does* behave as I expect/intend.  I can't tell how to pull out the request the Java API is sending over without monitoring the traffic, but if I understand the pattern then I would think these are isomorphic.  I've also confirmed that the Kotlin code is calling the Java API as intended based on my input.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently asking the question was enough to figure it out – each subquery needs its own builder.  Here's the modified code now working as expected:

```
val boolQuery = BoolQuery.of { boolBuilder ->
    query.forEachIndexed { index, char ->
        val prefix = if (index > 0) {
            "* "
        } else { "" }

        boolBuilder.must { mustBuilder ->
            val queryString = QueryStringQuery.of { queryBuilder -> queryBuilder
                .query("${prefix}${char}*")
            }
            mustBuilder.queryString(queryString)
        }
    }
    boolBuilder
}
```